# Scala immutable lists adding a 'Unit' element

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, immutability

Im a beginner at a scala and am looking for the best/idiomatic way to do what I intend to  do here.

This is what I want to do

```
def someMethod(obj:MyObj):List[String] = {
     List[String]() +: 
      {if (somecondition is satisfied) .. " element"} +: 
      { if (another condition) .. " something else " }


}
```

That is the method checks some properties of the input parameter object and adds elements to the List (that is to be returned) . If none of the conditions are satisfied , it should return an empty List.

1. Of course the code doesn't compile . But somehow, it seems intuitive to me that List[T] + Unit should return List[T] .  Why am I  wrong ?

And 2. Please tell me the right way to do this Scala .  If I were iterating over a list of conditions, I could have used comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write it like this:

```
def someMethod(obj:MyObj):List[String] = {
     List(
      if (somecondition is satisfied) " element", 
      if (another condition) " something else "
     ) collect{ case x: String => x }
}
```

Suppose all conditions are failed: you'll end up with `List(Unit,Unit)` first which will be *filtered* by type. Unit doesn't satisfy type condition inside collect, so result will be empty List of Strings

The good thing is that unlike `filter` method `collect` chooses as tight type as it can (so you'll get Sequence of Strings -- this will be infered from function inside collect).

Another possibility is to replace `.collect { ... }` with `flatten`, but you'll lose type information.

Comment: Can you please explain how this code works? In particular I have no idea what `..` does in Scala...

Comment: @ziggystar no magic here, in scala `..` is nothing, I've just copied some code from op snippet, and I guess he wan't to say that this is just. I've added details on how things work and removed `..` to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than filtering Unit, I would rather use unary or empty lists:

```
def someMethod(obj:MyObj): List[String] = {
    Nil ++
    ( if (somecondition is satisfied) List(" element") else Nil ) ++
    ( if (another condition) .. List(" something else ") else Nil ) ++
}
```

EDIT: Concerning your comment below, if you find the above code too verbose and hard to maintain, you can still create a helper function:

```
def optElem[T]( condition: Boolean)( value: => T ): Option[T] = if ( condition ) Option( value ) else None
def someMethod(obj:MyObj): List[String] = {
  Nil ++
  optElem (somecondition is satisfied)( " element") ++
  optElem (another condition)(" something else " )
}
```

Comment: Yep, much more smarten and efficient

Comment: btw, this is exactly what I did before posting the question ( I had used empty lists).  I found that much more verbose .. Essentially ,I was looking for a way which a new developer who happens to maintain the code in the future would find the least difficult

Answer (score 3):

`if`-`else` is an expression in Scala. What you have written becomes:

```
List[String]() +: 
      {if (somecondition is satisfied) {" element"; () } else () }+: 
      { if (another condition) { " something else "; () } else () }
```

As you can see, the common branch type is `Unit`.

The type of the whole expression would be `List[Any]` since that's the common supertype of `String` and `Unit`.

Some ways to achieve what you want:

```
// #1. Ugly.
def someMethod(obj:MyObj):List[String] = {
  val xs = List[String]() 
  val xs1 = if (somecondition is satisfied) xs :+ " element" else xs
  val xs2 = if (another condition) xs1 :+ " something else" else xs1
  xs2
}

// #2. Better, but uses mutable builder.
def someMethod(obj:MyObj):List[String] = {
  val b = List.newBuilder[String]
  if (somecondition is satisfied) b += " element"
  if (another condition) b += " something else"
  b.result
} 

// #3. Best way IMO, but computationally expensive.
def someMethod(obj:MyObj):List[String] = {
  List[String]() ++
  Option("element").filter(some condition) ++ // for more correct semantics
                                              // use LazyOption from Scalaz.
  Option("something else").filter(another condition)
}
```

Comment: If the filter condition is not a function of the element, then `someBool option "element"` is a nice pimp to use from Scalaz.

Comment: #3, I think this is what the `++:` method is designed for: `Option("element").filter(some condition) ++: Option("something else").filter(another condition) ++: Nil`. This should be more efficient because it prepends things.

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this is to construct a list of options then flatten the list.

```
def f(obj: MyObj): List[String] = {
  List(if (cond1(obj)) Some("element")        else None,
       if (cond2(obj)) Some("something else") else None).flatten
}
```